# azure python function runs locally in vscode but not in azure PAYG functon app. Issue with httpRequest.headers["referer"]?

Tags: python, azure, serverless

I am getting the following error message from the Azure logs:

```
Result: Failure Exception: KeyError: 'referer' Stack: File "/azure-functions-
host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 372, in 
_handle__invocation_request self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args,
 **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions 
host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 548, in __run_sync_func 
return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/createCheckoutSession/__init__.py", line 18, in main 
logging.info(req.headers["referer"]) File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure/functions/_http.py", line 27, in __getitem__ return 
self.__http_headers__[key.lower()]
```

I think the offending code is:

```
logging.info(req.headers["referer"])
logging.info(os.environ["stripe_api_key"])
BASEURL = req.headers["referer"] + "#"
```

Azure seems to be struggling to pull the referer from the req.headers.  It works in VScode.  I use the referer to build a redirect URL after a Stripe payment request. This redirect is obviously different in DEV, TEST and PROD.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I did some test on my side with the code below:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(req.headers["referer"])
    BASEURL = req.headers["referer"] + "#"

    return func.HttpResponse(
            BASEURL,
            status_code=200
    )
```

But both on local and Azure cloud, it works as excepted:

[image]

So could you pls have a check and let me know if you have any more questions?

Comment: looks like i'm deconstructing the function then..... :(.  Thanks for taking the time to test.

Comment: @AaronReese, welcome, if my post is helpful, could you pls accept it as an answer? And let me know if you have any further questions :)

Comment: will do once i've done some more investigation.  Do you know which version of Python you were running against?

Comment: @AaronReese, I am using Pythion 3.6

Answer (score 0):

After chasing my tail for several days, I have finally discovered that the answer is exactly what the error says it is.

The function is being called from and azurestaticapps.net deployment and by default this is ***NOT*** sending the Referer

**Extract of headers FROM DEV:**

```
Host: localhost:7071
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
```

**Extract of headers from staticapps.net**

```
Host: jumbletrailuk.azurewebsites.net
Origin: https://blue-plant-HiddenForSecurity.azurestaticapps.net
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
```

However when run/testing it in the Azure Functions portal that DOES use Referer so it wasn't failing there either.